# presta shop - to show how many memory has been used on product page

Tags: memory, limit, prestashop

I've got online store based on PrestaShop with huge amount of product attributes. About 10-20k... There is memory problem. On the product page, where Presta builds this big JS-array with all attributes-combinations, the 256MB of memory is too little, but 512 is OK.  I want to know how many memory I am using at now (near to 256 or 512), because I want to create more attribute-combination. How can I do this?

Comment: ask this question at Prestashop forum.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could manually reduce the size of the image before uploading it, or you could increase the memory limit by searching for and changing the memory_limit setting in php.ini, or add it if it doesn’t exist:

```
; Set memory limit in megabytes
memory_limit = 128M
```